# Multiprocessing and numpy, online processing while avoiding copying

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing

There are lots of questions about using multiprocessing with numpy and sharing arrays. But it seems to me like they all have the luxury of having the data available when the application starts which means it can be memory mapped without too much difficulty.

In contrast, I am trying to build a framework in which data is generated and then processed.

Basically I have a pipeline that looks something like this

```
Source --> Filter --> Destination
   |          |            |
   |          |            |
   ------------------------------> Controller / GUI
```

The source emits new data, which in my case are images from e.g. a video stream (stored as `numpy.ndarray` instances). The filter does calculations on the data and the destination does further calculation.
The Controller/GUI is just to be able to show previews, current progress, etc.

My current design is to make Source, Filter and Destination  `multiprocessing.Process` instances, and then I have `multiprocessing.Queue` instances that connects the processes.

But using Queues (or Pipes) for sharing data means the data is copied at each step. If possible, it would be nice to avoid these copies since I am quite sure (not measured yet though) that this lowers the performance.
Is there any reasonable way to avoid this?

#### Edit, random thoughts on possible solution

I guess what I really want is some kind of shared memory pool where I can store images and then just pass references to the processes.
Example:

1. Source produces an image and stores it in the shared memory pool at position `k`.
2. Source sends "There is a new image at location `k`" to Filter
3. One of two things:

   1. Filter decides that the image is bad and instructs the shared memory pool to remove the image at position `k`.
   2. or Filter decides that the image is ok and sends the "There is a filtered image at location `k`" to Destination.

I am not sure how difficult this would be to implement though, if anyone already has, or if it is indeed the best answer.
I'd like to hear your opinions.

Answer (score 0):

You might have success storing your numpy data in one or more [`multiprocessing.Manager`s](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-managers).  You'd still have to deal with the performance implications of serializing communication back and forth with the manager, but if you were careful, you could at least likely avoid having to pump the entire data structure across pickle/unpickle.

Edit:

Maybe you're looking at the problem the wrong way.  Instead of trying to pass data from one processing entity to the next, create a worker for each data entity, then perform all the calculations for that entity in that one worker.  Could you structure your code so that Source could just spawn a worker that would be responsible for actually generating and filtering the images, then have the worker notify Destination when it is done that new data is ready for presentation?  You'd still have to serialize some sort of token from Source to the workers, and the final data from the workers to the Destination, but you'd be able to get rid of at least 1 or 2 handoffs, and might be able to figure out a more efficient way to serialize what's left, since you'd only have to serialize the part of the data relevant to the Destination.

Comment: I have tried reading the documentation on Managers, but have not really managed (ha!) to figure out their greatness. Are you saying that Queue and Pipe pickles the data (which mean CPU cycles) and that using a custom manager I could instead send data raw (more I/O, less CPU)? If you care to expand on your answer that would be really helpful.

Comment: All data passing mechanisms (other than shared memory) using multiprocessing operate by serializing and deserializing data with pickle.  Managers do the same thing, but instead of passing an entire representation of the object back and forth, they wrap a proxy interface served via a local server around an object, then have other processes operate over that proxy interface instead of passing around the entire object.  Source would still have to feed the whole image in, and dest would have to pull the whole thing out, but filter might be able to get away with operating on just a piece of each.

Comment: Unfortunately, every step of my processing chain will need the full data.

Comment: I did update my question with some random thoughts, I'd be grateful if you could take a look at that as well.